# How to correctly store the date on the database from the model Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, model, save

please help me i'm using Laravel 5.4 and i want save on databese from model function.

This is my controller

```
public function addStockSizes(Request $request)
{
    if ($request->isMethod('post')) {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'size' => 'required',
        ]);

        $data['size'] = $request->input('size');
        $data['netSize'] = $request->input('net_size');
        $data['mouseText'] = $request->input('mouse_text');

        Stock_size::createSize($data);

        return redirect()->back()->with('success', true)->with('message', 
        'Size is successfully added');
    } else {
        $sizes = Stock::all();
        return view('admin.StockSize.addStockSizes', compact('sizes'));
    }
}
```

And this is my function in model

```
public static function createSize($data)
{
    $size = $data['size'];
    $netSize = $data['netSize'];
    $mouseText = $data['mouseText'];

    $model = new self();
    $model->size = $size;
    $model->net_size = $netSize;
    $model->mouse_text = $mouseText;
    $model->save();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`create`](https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_create) function on an Eloquent model. This function expects an associative array with the data for the database.

```
Stock_size::create($request->only(['size', 'net_size', 'mouse_text']));
```

Keep in mind that you might get a `MassAssignmentException` because model properties are guarded against this by default. This can be fixed by adding the fields that are inserted to the `$fillable` array of your model:

```
protected $fillable = ['size', 'net_size', 'mouse_text'];
```

Comment: i want create function in model which the save data

Comment: The create function does exactly that, there is no need to write another function.